# How to map a dataframe df (having two columns) with another dataframe df1(having three columns) and update it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

have a df1 with values

```
      0                1
0  abc def          unknown
1  uvw xyz          unknown
2  cricket ball     unknown
3  tennis racket    unknown
```

And df2 with values

```
     0        0         1
0   abc      def     password
1   cricket  ball    password1
2   tennis  racket   password2






.....

22610   uvw      xyz     password3
```

should map the df1 and df2 with 0 values and update 1 column in df1

Output should be

```
      0                1
0  abc def         | password
1  uvw xyz         | password3
2  cricket ball   | password1
3  tennis racket  | password2
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that creates df1 and df2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

Create new column in df2, which contains concatenation of two columns to match with df1 column:

```
df2['concat']= df2[0]+str(' ')+df2[0]
# added space to match with df1 and drop the df2[0] columns
```

Rename the column name of df1[0] to 'concat':

```
df1.rename({0:'concat'},inplace =True,axis=1)
```

Use merge method from pandas:

```
df1.merge(df2,on='concat')
```

and you will get the expected results .

Comment: keyerror:0    for this line      df2['concat']= df2[0]+str(' ')+df2[0]

Comment: maybe your column names are in string format. put it in commas df2['0']. also while loading data pandas update the column names if duplicates. Avoid giving duplicate names of a columns.